# Layer disappears on OpenLayers after specific zoom in

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

I have added some layer(s) and a base layer using OpenLayers v 2.11, layer does not appear when it first opened the page, but after zoom out  it does appear. Why is behaving in this way, are there any parameteres for always visible?

```
var map = new OpenLayers.Map("map");
var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("Google Streets", {
                numZoomLevels: 12
            });
map.addLayer(wms);
var wms2 = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Basic1", "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms",
           {
               layers: 'SomeLayers',
               transparent: true,
               numZoomLevels: 12
           }, {
               isBaseLayer: false
           });
map.addLayer(wms2);
var ls = new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher();
map.addControl(ls);
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.ZoomBox());
ls.maximizeControl();

map.setCenter(lonlat, 6);
```

Comment: you have to define numZoomLevels in the isBaseLayer section as numZoomLevels is openlayers options paremeters not wms getmap parameter.

Comment: Nice i'll post it as answer

Answer (score 5):

A openlayers wms layer has 4 parameters `name (string), url (string), getMap params (everything inside first {}), options params (everything inside second{})`

`numZoomLevels` is openlayers options parameter not wms getmap parameter. so it should be with the `isBaseLayer` option.